# Sent camera picture via intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I try to sent my photo via intent.

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

Intent intent=new Intent(this,AktivityPreview.class);
intent.putExtra("picture", data);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Second activity

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
byte[] arrayP=intent.getExtras().getByteArray("picture");
```

But before second activity launch I get error `FALED BINDER TRANSACTION`

Comment: your byte is larger than the maximum size allowed for intent(betn 500kb to 1mb). save the byte into a imagefile and send that file's path via a intent.

Comment: Glad that you solved it. let me post my comment as an answer it will be helpful to future visitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android's Binder transaction buffer fixed size(500kb to 1mb) and is shared by all transactions in your app. As your **byte[]** can be larger than the available buffer it will generate **FALED BINDER TRANSACTION** error or TransactionTooLarge exception.
Try saving the byte into a imagefile and send that file's path via a intent.